# Substrate node template build Error E0277

Tags: substrate

I followed this tutorial.
https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/create-your-first-substrate-chain/setup
when I run `cargo build --release` then got the error:

```
error[E0277]: `[parity_wasm::elements::Instruction; 15]` is not an iterator
   --> /home/ubuntu/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/pwasm-utils-0.18.2/src/stack_height/mod.rs:300:23
    |
300 |                 new_instrs.extend(new_seq);
    |                                   ^^^^^^^
    |                                   |
    |                                   expected an implementor of trait `IntoIterator`
    |                                   help: consider borrowing here: `&new_seq`
    |
    = note: the trait bound `[parity_wasm::elements::Instruction; 15]: IntoIterator` is not satisfied
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `IntoIterator` for `[parity_wasm::elements::Instruction; 15]`

   Compiling unsigned-varint v0.7.0
```

I used Ubuntu & cargo version 1.51.0
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever in doubt about the nightly version that is know to work, it is best to look at the [`shell.nix` file on substrate](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/shell.nix#L8) at the tag/release/branch you are building against. For example, on `master` as of 2021-10-11:

```hs
  rust-nightly = with nixpkgs; ((rustChannelOf { date = "2021-09-10"; channel = "nightly"; }).rust.override {...}
```

You can downgrade your toolchain (for wasm target too, needed for substrate builds) with any version using:

```
rustup uninstall nightly
rustup install nightly-<YYYY-MM-DD>
rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain nightly-<YYYY-MM-DD>
```

Then build with:

```
WASM_BUILD_TOOLCHAIN=nightly-<yyyy-MM-dd> cargo build --release
```

Comment: I got the version on shell.nix is `toolchain = with nixpkgs; (rustChannelOf { date = "2021-09-14"; channel = "nightly"; });`
But I still got the error  
`rustup default  
nightly-2021-09-14-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)`

Comment: error doing what? `rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain nightly-<YYYY-MM-DD>` ?

Comment: No, I change the default to 2021-09-14 successfully, but got the same error after run `cargo build --release` Seem that the version on shell.nix is not the right version.

Comment: In some repo on Github, there is no shell.nix file. Anywhere else can I find the version?

Comment: I ran successfully by `cargo +nightly-2021-09-14-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu build --release`
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your rust nightly toolchain is not compatible with the code written above. You need to downgrade it with nightly-2020-10-01 or some different version of nightly toolchain using `rustup install nightly-2020-10-01`